# Do fiber optics make any noise/sound that can be heard by the human ear?

Tags: power-engineering

In regards to, "...the noise sources in a fiber optic link include noise from the RF amplifiers in the transmitter, the laser diode, the photodiode and RF amplifiers in the receiver. Of which laser noise arises from random fluctuations in the intensity of the optical signal". So, in layman's term, you may sometimes "hear" noise(s) from fiber optic cable? I've lived in my house for 7 yrs. and during the last 2 yrs. there is an acoustical sound radiating around the community, I can hear it in my house and also hear it at my job (which is miles away from my house). When it first started, it was a sound that I heard once every few weeks or so for short time spans. Then, it was about every week; then, every few days (or so) during the week and finally/currently, it's every day 24 hrs. (day and night). I can't figure it out so am seeking some professional clues as to what it might be. Can anyone help? Believe me, it's definitely not that "hum" that I've heard mentioned. It's more of an acoustical, engine idle-type sound with what I would call some sort of periodic gear (or frequency shifts?). And, by the way, I can sometimes feel the floor vibrating ever-so-slightly and sometimes there are power surges through the refrigerator for a duration of time and through the restroom vents at work. Help, please? :o/

Comment: No. The "noise" we talk about in rd communication is not audible either (until you turn on the receiver set).

Comment: Does anyone near you hear the same noise at the same time?

Comment: you may have Tinnitus, go see your doctor

Comment: I know the type of sound you mean.  I hear something similar myself.  It may be tinnitus, though in my case doctors tell me my hearing is fine. I have never been able to record it, which points to it not being real.  It may also point to it beng really hard to record (very faint and very low frequency.). What it certainly won't be is noise from fiber optics.  That has signal noise, but not audible noise.  Though the equipment using the fiber may have noisy fans that you could hear.

Answer (score 7):

No. Fiber optics do not emit any audible sound under normal operation. The only things that reasonably make sound would be mechanical elements such as cooling fans, pumps, etc. or possibly poorly designed switching power supplies. Note that if a very large amount of optical power is sent through a fiber, enough to physically damage the fiber, then it is possible to get some sound out of it, but this is really only possible in laboratory conditions where many 10s or 100s of watts are sent down a fiber, and usually results in the destruction of the fiber and other expensive lab equipment.

"Noise" in this context is a technical team that refers to random, unwanted signal components that affect the transmission and reception of data in a communication system.